# Errror el tipo "type" de button react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, props

Me sale el siguiente error al intentar definirle un tipo al atributo "type" de button.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import React from 'react';

export const ButtonType = {
  BUTTON: "button",
  RESET: 'reset',
  SUBMIT: 'submit',
}

type Props = {
  onClick: () => {},
  children: React.ReactNode,
  disabled: boolean,
  type: React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
}

const Button = (props: Props) => {
  const { children, onClick, disabled, type } = props
  return (
    <button type={type} onClick={onClick} disabled={disabled}>
      { children }
    </button>
  )
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {},
  disabled: false,
  type: ButtonType.BUTTON
}

export default Button
```

No tengo idea cual sea del tipo que deba colocar para que no me lance el error, espero que me pueden ayudar gracias

Answer (score 0):

Los tipos que tienes definidos en

```
export const ButtonType = {
  BUTTON: "button", // <-- Tipo 'string'
  RESET: 'reset', // <-- Tipo 'string'
  SUBMIT: 'submit', // <-- Tipo 'string'
}
```

No son de tipo constante, por lo que se les asigna el tipo más general, en este caso `string`, al ser `string` tan general, no es compatible con los tipos de datos que debería recibir `type`. Para convertirlos a tipos más específicos puedes convertir todo el objeto como `constante`, con lo cual los tipos que quedan asignados para cada miembro quedan invariables

```
export const ButtonType = {
  BUTTON: "button", // <-- Tipo 'button'
  RESET: 'reset', // <-- Tipo 'reset'
  SUBMIT: 'submit', // <-- Tipo 'submit'
} as const;
```

Cuando definimos los tipos como constantes sabemos que estos no pueden cambiar a otra variante de `string`, ejemplo **SUBMIT** nunca será asginado a `perro`, el único valor que puede tener asignado es `submit`.

Prueba cambiando estas definiciones con `const`, probablemente ese sea tu problema :)